# FireDac persistent connections not updating

Tags: delphi, firedac

My application needs to define a persistent connection definition, but some times, needs to change the database that is connected.

So I used this code to create a definition:

```
OraCon: TFDConnection;
oDef: IFDStanConnectionDef;

....

OraCon.Connected := False;
oDef := FDManager.ConnectionDefs.FindConnectionDef('MyConn');
if (oDef <> nil) then
begin
  FDManager.DeleteConnectionDef('MyConn');
end;

oDef := FDManager.ConnectionDefs.AddConnectionDef;
oDef.Params.Clear;
oDef.Name := 'MyConn';
oDef.Params.Add('DriverId=Ora');
oDef.Params.Add('Database=' + edDB.Text);
oDef.Params.Add('User_name=' + edUser.Text);
oDef.Params.Add('Password=' + edPasswd.Text);

oDef.MarkPersistent;
oDef.Apply;
OraCon.ConnectionDefName := 'MyConn';
OraCon.Connected := True;
```

It works good and updates the FireDac definitions file correctly.
The problem is that my FDConnection component keeps connected to old database, instead the new one.

What I have to do to "refresh" this?

Comment: Disconnect, set the new definition and connect. Nothing else should be done. Is that what you did? I would not rely on the fact that the manager is _listening_ the changes and do that for you.

Comment: Yes, I did this

Comment: Maybe the connection params are cached by the TFDConnection. Have you tried setting ConnectionDefName to something different and then back to 'MyConn'? Or freeing it and creating a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I need only one reference to TFDConnection object.
I defined it in a singleton classe and now works.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I just ran into the same issue with Delphi 10.4. I'm using the TfrmFDGUIxFormsConnEdit form to let the user edit the connection and save it out to the default Ini file. However when the .ConnectionDefName was set the connection did not pickup the settings the user just entered, even though the settings were correctly written to the ini file. To work around this I had to build and set the connection string like this:

```
Connection.ConnectionString := ConnectionDef.BuildString();
Connection.Open;
```